# GScript to Convert multiple sheets from the same document to individual PDFs and send each PDF to an email address contained in cell B2 on each sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a script that will take each sheet in one file, convert each sheet to a PDF, and send that PDF to the recipient listed in that sheet.

1. Each recipient has a Sheet within the workbook titled after them.
2. Each sheet contains the email of the intended recipient in B2 of each sheet.

I have browsed a lot of other scripts and tried to piece it together with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you

```
    function myFunction(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

    var B2Values = [];
    sheets.forEach(function(elt,index){
    //Get all  your email adresses
    B2Values.push(sheets[index].getRange(2,2).getValue());
    });

    //For each sheet in your Spreadsheet, it create a temporary Spreadsheet
 //who got only one sheet, with your sheet values, 
// transform it as pdf, send the pdf by email to your B2 email adress and delete
//the temporary Spreadsheet

    sheets.forEach(function(elt, index){
    var temporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.create("NAME_OF_THE_FILE_WHO_WILL_BE_SENT");
    var temporaryId = temporarySS.getId();
    var dataToMove = sheets[index].getRange(1,1,sheets[index].getLastRow(),sheets[index].getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var openingTemporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temporaryId);
      dataToMove.forEach(function(elt){
      openingTemporarySS.appendRow(elt);
      })
     MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: B2Values[index],
        subject: "YOUR_SUBJECT",
        attachments: [openingTemporarySS.getAs('application/pdf')]
    })

    DriveApp.getFileById(temporaryId).setTrashed(true);

    });
    }
```

And this is an other version, I think if you got a lot of sheets, you should use that one :

```
function myFunction(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

var B2Values = [];
sheets.forEach(function(elt,index){
//Get all  your email adresses
B2Values.push(sheets[index].getRange(2,2).getValue());
});

var temporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.create("NAME_OF_THE_FILE_WHO_WILL_BE_SENT");
var temporaryId = temporarySS.getId();
var openingTemporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temporaryId);

sheets.forEach(function(elt, index){
var dataToMove = sheets[index].getRange(1,1,sheets[index].getLastRow(),sheets[index].getLastColumn()).getValues();
  dataToMove.forEach(function(elt){
  openingTemporarySS.appendRow(elt);
  })
 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: B2Values[index],
    subject: "YOUR_SUBJECT",
    attachments: [openingTemporarySS.getAs('application/pdf')]
})
openingTemporarySS.deleteRows(1,openingTemporarySS.getLastRow());
});

DriveApp.getFileById(temporaryId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: If I can ask for one more request. How could I go about adding a different cell, say B1 into the created/sent file name?